# How can I make browser use same outgoing port, when browsing one site?

Tags: http, browser, connection, port, tcp

When I inspect the connection with wireshark, every time the browser send request to host, it uses different port.
It is like that, even when browsing in a same tab, same site.
Can I make it use the same port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer** is you can't (not on Windows anyway and not on *nix without sacrificing speed and possibly breaking things.).

**Long answer** is while it is technically possible while developing an application to create the logic to request specific port from OS when establishing connection, for a good reason this is not usually how it's done.

In the case of a browser, when it renders a site it establishes multiple connections, each with different outgoing unique port number (OS provided). The pool of available ports is OS managed and it's called [Ephemeral Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). If you are to [limit the Ephemeral Poll](https://superuser.com/questions/1118735/how-are-source-ports-determined-and-how-can-i-force-it-to-use-a-specific-port) to a single port (possible on *nix systems) just when executing the process and quickly reversing the change you may be able to force the Browser to use that specific outgoing port, but somehow I don't think this will work very well.